# Jquery merge two fields in JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON object in JQuery that looks like:

```
["state":"06","population":9},{"state":"32","population":13},{"state":"01","population":4},
```

I want to end up with a JSON object like:

```
{"06":9,"32":13,"01":4}
```

How would I do this in JQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: Iterate over the array and copy the values into a new object? Don't really see the problem.. of course you have to first parse the JSON to a JavaScript array. Have a look at the MDN JavaScript Guide to learn the basics about how to work with arrays and objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would want to use the [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method. If `my_array` holds the original array you describe, this ought to do it:

```
var result = {};
$.each(my_array, function(index, val) {
  result[val.state] = val.population;
});
```

Comment: (`result` ends up with the output you describe)

Comment: Instead of having the arguments `index, val`, you can omit those and use `result[this.state] = this.population`. I'm not really sure which is *better* per se but I just figured I'd post this for completeness.

Comment: It's a good point. I'm in the habit of using the short syntax only when iterating over a jQuery collection and following `forEach` style (albeit in reverse—never got that!) for other types.